# How can i draw a bottom curve of the uiview using uibezierpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, curve

I'm tried to draw a bottom curve on UIimageview using uibezierpath. I don't know how to do that?

```
    - (void)setMaskTo:(UIView*)view byRoundingCorners: 
   (UIRectCorner)corners
   {
      UIBezierPath *rounded = [UIBezierPath 
      bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds

      byRoundingCorners:corners

      cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0)];
      CAShapeLayer *shape = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
      [shape setPath:rounded.CGPath];
      view.layer.mask = shape;
    }
```

i already tried like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcAlN.jpg

I expect the output of https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWBKi.jpg

Comment: You are doing it correctly. But instead of rounded rect path, try with a plain path and adding a curve to it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624357-addcurve

Comment: Sir. I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you get going...

[image]

With a `UIBezierPath`:

- move to point `A`
- add quad curve to point `B` with control point `C`
- add line to point `D`
- add line to point `E`
- close the path

Here's a simple `UIView` subclass:

```
@implementation BottomCurveView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    CGFloat y = rect.size.height - 80.0;
    CGFloat curveTo = rect.size.height;

    UIBezierPath *myBez = [UIBezierPath new];
    [myBez moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, y)];
    [myBez addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width, y) controlPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2.0, curveTo)];
    [myBez addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(rect.size.width, 0.0)];
    [myBez addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    [myBez closePath];

    CAShapeLayer *maskForPath = [CAShapeLayer new];
    maskForPath.path = myBez.CGPath;
    [self.layer setMask:maskForPath];
}

@end
```

That produces the above image for a 200-pt tall view.

Comment: @KannanSrinivas - this is just a "starting point" ... You would want to make the curve starting Y point a variable (or a percentage), instead of the hard-coded `80.0` that I used for this example.

Comment: ya ok bro. i can try to change the value 80.0 and check it.

Comment: Perfect answer, Thank you @DonMag for your help!!